# How to update credit card and the phone number?

Tags: google-account, account-management

I am trying to locate my Google account settings but can not get to the right screen. I am trying to update my credit card and phone number information.

Answer (score 1):

- **go to** **https://myaccount.google.com/payments-and-subscriptions**
- **select what you want to change**

[image: 0]

---

- **for phone number go to** **[https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup/](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup/1?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2F)**

[image: 9]